# Unable to connect to Tor using requests whereas I did the same using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, tor

I've written two scripts in python: one using `selenium` and the other using `requests` to connect to ***http://check.torproject.org*** using ***Tor*** and get this piece of text ***Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor*** from there in order to be sure I'm doing things in the right way.

When I use the below script I cen get the text smoothly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

torexe = os.popen(r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:9050')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.not").text
print(item)

driver.quit()
```

However, when I try to do the same using `requests`, I get an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

torexe = os.popen(r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe")

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.proxies['http'] = 'socks5://localhost:9050'
    res = s.get("http://check.torproject.org")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one("h1.not").text
    print(item)
```

***How can I get the same text using `requests` from that site?***

When I use this `print(soup.title.text)`, I can get this text `Sorry. You are not using Tor.` which clearly indicates that the `requests` is not made via `Tor`.

Comment: For one, Tor Browser uses port 9150 for SOCKS, so unless you have a Tor daemon running, the request is either failing, or not using the proxy.  Do some debugging and print out the response to see what you're getting.

Comment: I followed the examples of some blog posts. [This is one of such blog](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/using-tor-with-the-python-request-library-79015b2606cb) where the suggested port is 9050 for socks5h. However, I tried this `https://httpbin.org/ip` within the above script and found a different ip @drew010.

Comment: 9050 is the right port if you have the Tor daemon running, but since you used popen in the example to launch Tor Browser, it will use 9150 (as not to conflict with regular Tor installs).  I would have thought it would have resulted in an exception if Tor were not running on that port.  At least that's what happens for me: `Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy localhost:9950: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.  I'd also suggest switching to `socks5h`, and I think I know why it didn't work now.  Posting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check.torproject.org forces HTTPS so when requests follows the redirect to `https://check.torproject.org` you are no longer using the SOCKS proxy since it was only specified for the `http` protocol.

Make sure to set the proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS.  Also, to resolve DNS names over Tor and not leak DNS requests, use `socks5h`.

```
s.proxies['http']  = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
s.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
```

This should result in your test working properly.

Comment: You are absolutely corrrect. Thanks a zillion. You made my day.

Comment: That gives me this error
```
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy localhost:9050: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: @KuneMohith Connection refused means Tor is not listening on port 9050.  Check the torrc and make sure [SOCKSPort](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort) is set to 9050. If you are using Tor browser it is 9150.

Comment: Yeah! It's working now. I have restarted the tor services by `sudo service tor restart`